# How should we batch the inputs before feeding to the torch modules?

Tags: lua, torch

Which dimension of the input should be used for batching in torch?

I have 1000 examples for training and each training example is of the dimension 10*5. Now, i want to feed this data into a Sequencer as a batch of 100 examples each.

How should i structure my input? Should the dimension of each batch of input be 100*10*5 (first dimension used for batch) or 10*100*5 (second dimension used for batch) ?

Would appreciate links to relevant documents explaining the followed convention.

Does the convention change for containers and modules?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is usually a Tensor of size `100*10*5`. If it is an image it could be that you have to consider the number of channels so it would be `batchSize*channels*width*height`. This will make the data easy to access, you just need to do `inputs[{i}]` to retrieve your data. Consider to create another Tensor to store the labels (if you use labelled data). You can find the example here. https://github.com/torch/tutorials/blob/master/2_supervised/4_train.lua#L131

I'd recommend you to have a look at the tutorials, there you will see how the data has to be "prepared" before feeding the network https://github.com/torch/tutorials

Comment: Thanks Manuel, actually i am confused after seeing this - https://github.com/Element-Research/rnn#rnn.Sequencer  Here, the second dimension is used for batch by default. I think different containers are using different conventions.

Comment: @VikramGupta You are right! in this case, seems like the sequencer container requires a different input shape.